# Response Redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventeArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(myselect.SelectedValue.ToString(), true);
}
```

Above is my code, I already put a breakpoint on `.SelectedValue` and it's recognizing the value, but when I click on the button it shows this message:

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: What value you have in `myselect.SelectedValue.ToString()`?

Comment: A path to a pdf.

Comment: Is it the complete URL or the relative value?

Comment: The path looks like this: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Site\Site\PDF\PC\1. View PDF.pdf

Comment: Response.redirect to other then http or ftp would result in error.

Comment: So what do i have to do to open the pdf in another tab of browser?

Comment: Place the pdf in a folder in your project in the solution explorer and use the relative path. @jorgehvieirasilva

Comment: But the pdf path is on a database, so i cant use relatives paths i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do what you need, you must download the file to the client. Response.Redirect as people mentioned redirects to URL. 
To make it open in the browser you need the below :

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventeArgs e)
{

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=MyFile.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(myselect.SelectedValue.ToString());
Response.End();
}
```

For Content-Disposition you have two choices :

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.ext") : Prompt will appear for file download

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext") : the browser will try to open the file within the browser.
```

Comment: Where do i add the Response.AddHeader line?

Comment: sorry its append header to i will update it. Showing you examples of the content-disposition header to force the browser to show the file if applicable like pdf / excel ..etc. Or to show the download prompt

Comment: OMG IT WORKED, FINALLY.

Comment: But, how can i open the pdf in a new tab? xD

Comment: :D :D yaay .. happy to help jorge , if helped dont forget to mark the answer :) .. opening in another tab will require you another way of implementation :) we can move to chatting to tell you the way.

Comment: How do we chat here? Im a noob in this site, first time using it ahaha (:

Answer (score 1):

Your sample is assuming that a site e.g. `1.aspx` or `221.aspx` exists. You are only passing some selected value.

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventeArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(myselect.SelectedValue.ToString(), true);
}
```

you need to redirect to some kind of action like:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id) {

    // Your code to retrieve a byte array of your file
    var thefileAsByteArray = .....

    return File(thefileAsByteArray, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, 'DownloadFilenName.pdf');       
}
```

Then you would need to change your onClick metho like:

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventeArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("Download.aspx?id=" + myselect.SelectedValue.ToString(), true);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i didnt understand what i have to do in public FileResult .....

Comment: @jorgehvieirasilva do the Logic in the Download Method instead of submitting a complete path to your pdf

Comment: There isn´t a way to do this without downloading the file?

Comment: Maybe. See the other answer.